# Image as response not working in power automate

Tags: php, image, power-automate

My goal is to return an image as an api response, without storing it on the server.
The image is sent to the api, the api converts the image from gif to png.

It's working in postman, but it isn't working in power automate.
In power automate my body is empty ...

Did some tests, the code is executed, unfortunately the image is not returned.

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
        //header("Content-type: image/".$params['format']);

        require('image_converter.php');
        
        //create object of image converter class
        $obj = new Image_converter();

        //echo file_get_contents('php://input');

        //$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        
        echo $data;//["\$multipart"];//[1]["body"]["\$content"];
        
        //$converted_image = $obj->convert_image($params['format'], $data["\$multipart"][1]["body"]["\$content"]);
        //echo $data;
        $converted_image = $obj->convert_image($params['format'], json_decode($data, true)["\$content"]);
        echo $converted_image;
```

Image converter

```
    $binary = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image));
    
    //to png
    if($convert_type == 'png'){
        $image_quality = floor(10 - ($image_quality / 10));
        ob_start();
        ImagePNG($binary, NULL, $image_quality);
        $result = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $result;
    }
```

Postman request headers:

[image]

Postman response headers:

[image: Postman headers]

Postman response:

[image: Postman response]

Power automate request header:

[image]

Power automate response:

[image: Power automate response]

Postman request:

[image]

Postman response (echo file_get_contents('php://input'); )

[image]

Power automate request:

[image]

Power automate response (echo file_get_contents('php://input'); ):

[image]

Comment: The power automate version seems to lack many of the request headers the postman one has

Comment: How is this PowerAutomate? Don’t mean desktop? If so, please change the tag.

Comment: *"Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?"* Log the input and you will find out. It's basic debugging...

Comment: @ADyson: added some request headers, still same result

Comment: @Skin, it is power automate, not on desktop. https://make.powerautomate.com/

Comment: @Olivier, I was thinking output issues, one platform is working, while the other one isn't. I'll check to print the input as a response to do some debugging

Comment: Then please add the relevant screenshots that show the PowerAutomate components.

Comment: Update to include the `body` of postman and PowerAutomate for the `POST` request.

Comment: @Olivier: You were right, the input in my original request was received differently. Some ID's were added, while they weren't in power automate mentioned. Removed all request data that wasn't necessary, but the request is still received in a different format. Tried with the headers I've added, but no luck, in my last attempt I removed almost all headers, still no result.

Comment: @SamNseir , I've added the request from both platforms, they are identical. But the way PHP receives it is differently. Do I need to add something to my headers in Power Automate, or can I write some PHP to workaround my issue?

Comment: Power Automate sends the GIF directly. Your script expects JSON, so of course it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess the "Power Automate request" you have posted is just a JSON representation of the request. It's not the literal content that is actually sent.

Comment: @Olivier , Correct. The JSON representation is the response from another call, to create an image (unfortunately GIF, so I need to convert it)

I've changed my code to support the json format and to support the image format.

Answer (score 0):

The "Power Automate request" is just a JSON representation of the request. It's not the literal content that is actually sent.

I've updated the code to support the json format and to support the actual image .

```
        header("Content-type: image/".$params['format']);
        $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        //$data = base64_decode($data);

        $image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
        if ($image === false) {
            //echo json_decode($data, true)["\$content"];
            $image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode(json_decode($data, true)["\$content"]));
        }
        
        if ($image === false) {
            echo 'Please provide an image';
            return;
        }

        require('image_converter.php');
        
        //create object of image converter class
        $obj = new Image_converter();
        
        $converted_image = $obj->convert_image($params['format'], $image );
        echo $converted_image;
```

Image converter class

```
function convert_image($convert_type, $image, $image_quality=100)
{
    //to png
    if($convert_type == 'png'){
        //third parameter for ImagePng is limited to 0 to 9
        //0 is uncompressed, 9 is compressed
        //so convert 100 to 2 digit number by dividing it by 10 and minus with 10
        $image_quality = floor(10 - ($image_quality / 10));
        ob_start();
        ImagePNG($image, NULL, $image_quality);
        $result = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $result;
    }
    
    //to jpg
    if($convert_type == 'jpg'){
        ob_start();
        imageJpeg($image, NULL, $image_quality);
        return base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
    }       
    //to gif
    if($convert_type == 'gif'){
        ob_start();
        imageGif($image, NULL, $image_quality);
        return base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
    }               
    return false; 
}
```